# Ошибка Automation error (Error 440) при работе с .NET библиотекой в VBA

Tags: vba, vb.net, com

Собрал библиотеку по примеру данной [статьи](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3511/Exposing-NET-Components-to-COM).

Код интерфейса:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

<Guid("89439AD1-756F-4f9c-BFB4-18236F63251E"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)>
Public Interface IXCorelDll
    <DispId(1)>
    Function GetMonth() As Integer
    <DispId(2)>
    Function GetDay() As Integer
    <DispId(3)>
    Function GetYear() As Integer
End Interface
```

Код класса:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports XCorelDll

<Guid("1376DE24-CC2D-46cb-8BF0-887A9CAF3014"), ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None), ProgId("XCorelDll.Numbers")>
Public Class XCorelDll
    Implements IXCorelDll

    Public Sub New()

    End Sub

    Public Function GetDay() As Integer Implements IXCorelDll.GetDay
        GetDay = DateTime.Now.Day
    End Function

    Public Function GetMonth() As Integer Implements IXCorelDll.GetMonth
        GetMonth = DateTime.Now.Month
    End Function

    Public Function GetYear() As Integer Implements IXCorelDll.GetYear
        GetYear = DateTime.Now.Year
    End Function


End Class
```

Выставляю настройки проекта:

- Приложение -> Сведения о сборке -> Сделать сборку видимой для COM
- Компиляция -> Регистрация для СОМ-взаимодействия

Утилитой sn создаю ключ:

```
sn.exe -k key.snk
```

Регистрирую сборку в реестре:

```
regasm XCorelDll.dll /tlb:XCorelDll.tlb
```

Далее копирую сборку в GAC:

```
gacutil /i XCorelDll.dll
```

Подключаю библиотеку типов в CorelVBA.
Пытаюсь использовать так:

```
Sub RunCorelVBA()

    Dim i As XCorelDll.XCorelDll
    Set i = New XCorelDll.XCorelDll

    MsgBox "The date is: " & i.GetMonth & "/" & i.GetDay & "/" & i.GetYear

End Sub
```

На строке

```
Set i = New XCorelDll.XCorelDll
```

Вылетает ошибка:
Automation error (Error 440)

В чем может быть проблема не могу понять.

- Win 8.1
- Visual Studio 2015